# Change Path Data property programmatically

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a button in XAML like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btnClose" Style="{DynamicResource ToolbarButton}">
    <Viewbox>
        <Path Style="{DynamicResource button_bg}" />
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

And in resource defined:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="mainBackgroundColor" Color="#FF1C1C1B"/>

<StreamGeometry x:Key="squareBackground">F1M0,60L60,60 60,0 0,0z</StreamGeometry>
<EllipseGeometry x:Key="circleBackground" Center="30,30" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30"/>

<Style x:Key="button_bg" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource mainBackgroundColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="{DynamicResource squareBackground}"/>
</Style>
```

Button background is changing well when i set different values in XAML: squareBackground/circleBackground.

I am also able to change colors with this code:

```
Application.Current.Resources("mainBackgroundColor") = New SolidColorBrush(CType(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF1C1C1B"), Color))
```

But how can i change this Data Property of a "button_bg" dinamically in code?
Tried like this:

```
CType(Application.Current.Resources("button_bg"), Style).Setters.Add(New Setter(System.Windows.Shapes.Path.DataProperty, Application.Current.Resources("circleBackground")))
```

But no luck...

Comment: `Control.DataContextProperty` is not the dependency property identifer for the `Path.Data` property. Try `Path.DataProperty` instead.

Comment: Why don't use triggers instead ?

Comment: @Clemens I tried, this code is after many tryouts... i will update question. Using Path.DataProperty i get error:
After a "SetterBaseCollection" is in use (sealed), it can not be modified.

Comment: @synapse I need to update control based on external inputs, so its not possible with triggers (that was my first solution, btw). :-)